# How to reference xaml stylesheet from another xaml stylesheet

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a stylesheet called `Styles.xaml` and it has all the initial styles but has gotten so cluttered over time. Now I am introducing a second style called `Styles2.xaml`, I want to move the color elements from `Styles.xaml` to `Styles2.xaml` and have `Styles.xaml` reference those from `Styles2.xaml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add a reference to it with using MergedDictionary syntax like so, assume code below is from `Style2.xaml`

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Kliva.XAMLResources">

    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    <Style x:Name="KlivaButton"
           TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource KlivaDarkBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource OpenSansFontLight}" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="22" />
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```